# Что бы вы посоветовали для создания 2D схем помещений?

Tags: android, opengl, android-canvas

Может есть какая-нибудь готовая библиотека для того, чтобы пользователь мог создавать примерно такие схемы:

.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. чтобы можно было создавать на схеме стены, назначать им размеры, размещать на этих стенах окна/двери, соединять стены между собой, отображать их размеры, углы между ними и т.д., добавлять SVG-объекты, которые тоже можно было бы вращать/масштабировать. Типа как очень упрощенная версия Floor Plan Creator'а.

Или это только руками все делать? Взять какой-нибудь GlSurfaceView  и вперед, изучать OpenGL?

Может быть даже можно использовать что-то, что обычно используют для созданя игр? Типа Cocos2D, LibGDX, Andengine?

Если использовать GlSurfaceView, то тут нужны знания в области математики и графики? Матрицы, шейдеры? Или для 2D это не так страшно?

Или можно обойтись Canvas?

Comment: Поищи, есть сайты с 3д планировщиками домов/квартир/помещений. Загугли что-то типа "plan house 3d". Узнай терминологию, поищи библиотеки.

Comment: Мне ни к чему 3D, хватит и 2D. Гугление на русском дает мало результатов, а на английском для слова "схема" очень и очень общий перевод. Получается что-то типа sketch, draw, scheme, но по этим словам (в связке с другими словами, разумеется) находится совсем не то :)

Comment: Гуглите на английском "house plan 2d layout floorplan". sketch (набросок), draw (рисовать), scheme (схема) все относятся к другой тематике.

Answer (score 1):

В теории вы можете создать некие объекты(элементы) разметки вашего/иного плана. В последствии использовать, размещая на `Canvas`. Пример кода.

```java
class Door
{
    //параметры
    float x,y,rotate,scale;
    //конструктор
    Door(float x, float y, float rotate,float scale)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.rotate = rotate;
        this.scale = scale;
    }
    //изменение масштаба
    void Scaling(float scale){
        this.scale = scale;
        Draw();
    }
    //Сдвинуть
    void Move(float x, float y,){
        this.x += x;
        this.y += y;
        Draw();
    }
    //переместить
    void MoveTo(float x, float y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        Draw();
    }
    void Draw(){
        //Отрисовать элемент
    }
}
```

Так как построение планов подразумевает функциональные особенности, их так же можно реализовать объектами.
Например линейку/рулетку:

```java
class Roulette
{
    float x1,y1,x2,y2,length,rotate; 
    Door(float x, float y, float rotate)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.rotate = rotate;
        Calculation();
        Draw();
    }
    void Calculation(){
        if(rotate==0)
            this.length =
        else if(rotate==180) 
            this.length =
        else if(rotate==90) 
            this.length =
        else if(rotate==-90)  
            this.length =   
        else
            this.length =  
    }
    void Draw(){
        //Отрисовать элемент
    }
}
```

Я рекомендую использовать Observer для отображения всех элементов за один кадр.

> [Observer](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/observer) - это поведенческий паттерн проектирования, который создаёт
>   механизм подписки, позволяющий одним объектам следить и реагировать на
>   события, происходящие в других объектах.